# Web browser with memory management

Tags: browser

Is there any web browser with manual memory management exist?

So I can limit memory consumption, also it would be nice if can handle 'infinite' number of tabs.

Comment: I think [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) is a more appropriate place to ask that.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/597607/web-browser-with-memory-management  seems they don't think so.

Comment: I see. They see it as a product recomendation. Dully noted.